# Update сущности в EntityFramework, другим экземпляром сущности?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. Реализую в проекте доменный слой (DAL). Написал для него тесты, и все основные CRUD операции работы с репозиторием протестировал. Один из проектов которому необходимы данные из слоя DAL, это WPF приложение.
Планирую через autoMapper создавать копии объектов нужных мне (чтобы не делать байндинг напрямую к локальному кэшу EF). Столкнулся с проблемой обновления данных.

СУЩНОСТЬ СТАНЦИЯ

```
    public class Station
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ecp код станции")]
    public int EcpCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ, СОЗДАНИЕ КОПИИ, РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЕ КОПИИ, СОХРАНЕНИЕ КОПИИ.

```
        var station = _unitOfWork.StationRepository.GetById(1);
        var copyStation = new Station
        {
            Id = station.Id,
            Name = "qqqq",                          //Поменяли значение
            EcpCode = station.EcpCode,
            Description = station.Description
        };
        _unitOfWork.StationRepository.Update(copyStation);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
```

РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    protected CisDbContext Context { get; }
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; }



    public GenericRepository(CisDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);       //ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ!!!!!!!!! (объект с таким ID уже есть)
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity, int pkDetached)
    {
        var existing = GetById(pkDetached);
        if (existing != null)
            Context.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Detached;


        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

При выполнении `Update` возникает исключение

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>
> > EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
> >
> > Additional information: Attaching an entity of type
> >     'Domain.Entities.Station' failed because another entity of the same
> >     type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when
> >     using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
> >     'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
> >     conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
> >     have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
> >     the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
> >     then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
> >     appropriate.

Для решения проблемы я добавил в репозиторий метод

```
   public virtual void Update(TEntity entity, int pkDetached)
    {
        var existing = GetById(pkDetached);
        if (existing != null)
            Context.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Detached;


        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Т.е. я отсоединяю имеющееся свойство с таким же `ID` перед       `DbSet.Attach(entity)`;

В данном случае сработает, но если в сущности будут ссылки на другие типы (связи с другими таблицами). то проблема возникает опять.

Кто сталкивался с таким прошу помочь)))

Comment: Если метод Get возвращает копию объекта, тогда метод Update не должен добавлять эту копию в контекст, а искать в контексте соответствующий оригинал и синхронизировать его с копией.

Comment: Метод Get возвращает сам объект из базы, на его основе создается новый объект с таким же Id. Новый объект редактируется и должен заменить собой старый в базе (значениями своих полей заменить старые значения).

Comment: Я на самом деле выразился слишком образно и в отрыве от вашего кода. Под методами Get\Update я подразумевал ваш код в начале и в конце фрагмента под заголовком ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ, как если бы он был поделен на отдельные метода. Так получилось случайно. Я хотел всего лишь сказать, что если вы сделали копию объекта чтобы произвести над ним действия, то нельзя эту копию добавлять в контекст. Логически верно будет найти в контексте оригинал, и синхронизировать изменения, после этого сохранить их в БД.

Comment: я понял вас. Но это довольно сложно, ведь если меняются и вложенные объекты (выбор из списка объекта из другой таблицы), то нужно найти и выбранный объект по Id. Ну и так все связи нужно привести обратно в соответствие с контекстом. Хм думал будет проще.

Comment: на днах столкнулся с такой ошибкой, в моем случае это было из-за того что автомаппер создавал новый объект. [это решение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32403237/3373603) мне помогло